# Mobile JavaScript drop-down menu doesn't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mobile menu with a mix of CSS and JavaScript. I'm able to get the menu to open properly the first time, but I can't figure out how to get the next layer of drop-downs to open. If you need to see what the menu looks like, [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH08j.jpg)

Here is my JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // append plus symbol to every list item that has children
    $('#mobile-nav .parent').append('<span class="open-menu fa fa-angle-down"></span>');

    // fix non-scrolling overflow issue on mobile devices
    $('#mobile-nav > ul').wrap('<div class="overflow"></div>');
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        var vph = $(window).height(); // 57px - height of #mobile-nav
        $('.overflow').css('max-height', vph);
    });

    // global variables
    var menu = $('.overflow > ul');
    var bg = $('html, body');

    // toggle background scrolling
    function bgScrolling() {
        // if menu has toggled class... *
        if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
            // * disable background scrolling
            bg.css({
                'overflow-y': 'hidden',
                'height': 'auto'
            });
        // if menu does not have toggled class... *
        } else {
            // * enable background scrolling
            bg.css({
                'overflow-y': 'visible',
                'height': '100%'
            });
        }
    }

    // menu button click events
    $('.menu-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // activate toggles
        menu.slideToggle(250);
        menu.toggleClass('open');
        bgScrolling();
    });

    // list item click events
    $('.open-menu').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('ul').slideToggle(250);
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});
```

Here is my CSS

```css
.logo {
  color:#24678d;
  font-size:2.1rem;
  padding:.65rem 1rem;
  position:absolute;
}

.menu-button {
  color:#24678d;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:33px;
  padding: 10px 30px 0px 0px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
}

.open-menu {
  color:#24678d;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:1rem;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:20px;
  transition:transform 250ms ease;
}

/* Generated Overflow Element */
.overflow {
  margin-top:57px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
/* Menu Styles */
.rotate { transform:rotate(135deg); }

#mobile-nav {
  background-color:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

#mobile-nav ul {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  display:none;
  margin:0 1rem;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul:first-child {
  background-color:transparent;
}

#mobile-nav ul li {
  border-top:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.075);
  list-style:none;
  margin-bottom:0;
  position:relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color:#24678d;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1rem;
  padding:1rem 0;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
}

#mobile-nav ul ul {
  margin:0;
}

#mobile-nav ul ul li {
  border-top:none;
  padding-left:1rem;
}
```

Finally, the HTML for the mobile menu

```
<div id="mobile-nav"><!--== Starts Mobile Menu ==-->
      <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img class="mobile-img-logo" src="img/mobile-logo.png" alt="Tennessee Interventional and Imaging Associates"></a></div>
        <div class="menu-button">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="menu-icon menu-icon-3">
              <span class="bar bar-1"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-2"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-3"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="pay.html">Pay Your Bill</a></li>
          <li class="parent">
              <a href="#">Locations</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Erlanger Health System</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Murphy Medical Center</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mountain Lakes Medical Center</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="parent">
              <a href="#">Services and Procedures</a>
              <ul>
                  <li class="parent">
                      <a href="#">Diagnostic Imaging</a>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Responsive</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="parent">
                    <a href="#">Interventional Radiology</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Meet The Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--== Ends Mobile Menu ==-->
```

If someone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript just add the class `open` to your menu `ul`. You must implement what that means with css. For example:

```
#mobile-nav ul.open {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution to your question I think.

**Parent functionality**

I've been able to create a menu that has nested your submenus inside, these aren't visible until the parent menu is clicked on.

I achieved this by replacing your click handler on the ul elements with this simplified one using the `.parent` class as a target

```
$('.parent').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // added e.stopPropagation(); to prevent
    // child triggering parents event
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(250);
});
```

Please note, you have to initally hide the submenus using jQuery also when your document loads for example:

```
  $('.parent').children('ul').hide();
```

**Child link functionality**

To get your nested child links to function correctly, I've made some adjustments. Firstly, on each `a` tag you will need to add the class `child__link` after that, this javascript will restore the expected behaviour to your nested child links.

```
 $('.child__link').on('click', function(e){
    // as usual stop the events bubbling up
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // set the location to the intended href attribute
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  });
```

I also had to delete some phantom CSS and JS that was applying effects that I think perhaps you have moved away from (such as the `.rotate` class and `display:none` on some `ul` and `li` elements). Unfortunately I can't recall from where exactly.

I've put my answer into a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/jrmclaren/pen/zjoxJE).

FYI – I've also replaced your icons with placeholders because they were missing links

Good luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can we go about modifying this to include the multi-level drop-down? As of now, the parent menu opens fine. If a parent menu has a parent menu inside (and additional drop-down after the first one), the first drop-down will close instead of showing the next layer.

Comment: Hi Taylor, I've added `e.stopPropagation();` to the click event which should prevent children from firing the parent's click handler. You can read more about how it works [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) 

This seems to have fixed the issue, you can test the results on [my codepen](https://codepen.io/jrmclaren/pen/zjoxJE?editors=1010).

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help with my problem. JavaScript is a new language for me, so we all must go through the learning phase. The last problem I will solve is getting the links inside parent menu's to link properly. As of now, they do not work.

Comment: No worries. It's a fun language, you'll grow to love it! I'm not sure I understand your last problem? Could you define your expected behaviour, and what is currently happening? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well. In the mobile menu, any link under the parent class does not work. For instance, "Pay your bill" works, but "Locations" will not.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see the section **Child link functionality** and as always you can refer to [the codepen](https://codepen.io/jrmclaren/pen/zjoxJE) Cheers!

Comment: Any luck @TaylorParker? :)